# Content script not executing in new window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that, when clicked, opens a new incognito window and performs some DOM action on it. These are the files I'm using:

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "SampleExtension",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "incognito": "spanning",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://www.google.com"
  ]
}
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.windows.create({
    "url": "http://www.google.com", 
    "focused": true, 
    "incognito": true
});

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    "file": "myscript.js", 
    "run_at": "document_end", 
    "all_frames": true
});
```

**myscript.js**

```
document.querySelector('a[target]').click();
```

The extension opens the new window, but my content script doesn't seem to be executing. Any thoughts?

**Edit:** Added `"incognito": "spanning"` to the manifest. Still doesn't work, however.

Comment: you will have to enable your extension in incognito mode on `chrome://extensions`

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. Still doesn't seem to be executing.

Comment: try adding the key in your manifest: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito

Comment: Added `"incognito": "split"` to the manifest. Still not working.

Comment: Scratch that. Made it `"incognito": "spanning"`. No difference, however.

Comment: executeScript should be inside a callback of `create` because chrome API is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I understand that you have enabled to run in Incognito Mode. Extensions are disabled by default and, hence, it would not run otherwise.

Secondly, your match pattern needs to end with a slash:

```
"matches": ["http://www.google.com/"],
```

Thirdly, Google will redirect you to its https version, hence I would improve the [match pattern](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) like this:

```
"matches": ["*://www.google.com/"],
```

Still, it didn't work for me as I was redirected to my local Google domain. Hence, I had to do add more:

```
"matches": [
    "*://www.google.com/*",
    "*://www.google.com.sg/*"
  ],
```

Also, I added the final wildcard, because Google was adding some ?urlParams that I had to match too. And this made it work. Note that I tried with other pages like `"*://www.stackoverflow.com/*",` and it was easier than Google :)

*In case your Google page was just a test, I'd advise to use some less redirected pages to test with.*

A final note: I do not think it's possible to use the wildcard for the domain (I tried). However, you can request all the main domains, or request all_pages and then add the logic for Google only on my_script.js to decide whether to execute the action or not. (However, this last piece is not ideal).

---

Edit post comments:

It seems your function fails because the element is not loaded yet. An easy way to solve this is by doing an interval which checks whether the element is on the page. When it finds it, clicks it and removes the interval.

```
// Function which clicks element if existing and clears interval after doing it.
var clickLink = function() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('a[target]').length > 0) {
    clearInterval(waitAndClick); // stop interval
    document.querySelector('a[target]').click(); // click element.
  }
}

// Run click function every second, until it clicks it.
var waitAndClick = setInterval(clickLink, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. The actual URL I'm opening isn't Google though. :P I did add the slash to the end of my match pattern however, but it still isn't working. And the page certainly isn't getting redirected elsewhere.

Comment: This worked for me. What page are you being opening and what's your match pattern? Did you enable the extension in Incognito Mode? I'd also advise that you do an alert('hello'); to make sure it's not firing :)

Comment: Excellent. The content script does seem to be executing. But the `click` on the DOM element doesn't seem to working - I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null` error. This could possibly be because the script is executing before the DOM has fully loaded. But shouldn't this precisely be taken care of by the `"run_at": "document_end"` key of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`? The `click` works when I try it manually on the console after the page has loaded.

Comment: Yes, given that there's an element if you ran that selector on the command line, that means that the element is not loaded. One way to do this is just to do a setInterval();


`// Function which clicks element if existing and clears interval after doing it.
var clickLink = function() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('a[target]').length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('a[target]').click(); // click element.
    clearInterval(waitAndClick);
  }
}

// Run click function every second, until it clicks it.
var waitAndClick = setInterval(clickLink, 1000);`

Comment: Yes, I did a similar hacky `setTimeout` to make sure the page fully loads. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: setTimeout is good, but can fail if page takes too long to load. Interval should be better in avoiding this situation :) Talking from experience.